# How to switch terminal emulator for locally connected display?

Tags: lxterminal

I've written a cool Python script that uses `curses` to display colored text. When I SSH to the pi from my Mac, the terminal emulator is `xterm-256color` and everything looks great. However I can not get the script to run properly on the 5" HDMI display that is connected directly to the pi.

[The default raspberry pi terminal emulator is LXTerminal](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/usage/terminal/)

At the command line:

```
$ echo $TERM
linux
```

I have already tried:

`sudo update-alternatives –config x-terminal-emulator`

...and that menu still shows my selection as `xterm` however this has no effect, even after restart, on `echo $TERM` or the actual display behavior.

I have also tried including this in my Python script (against all stackexchange recommendations not to...):

```
os.environ['TERM'] = 'xterm-256color'
```

...and in this case a few of the curses commands work, but clearly some escape codes are cross-wired and there are some unexpected results (some text is blinking instead of displaying green, etc)

Finally, I tried just running `xterm` at the command line:

```
xterm: Xt error: Can't open display:                                                                                              
xterm: DISPLAY is not set
```

So how can I permanently set `xterm-256color` as my terminal application for the connected HDMI monitor? Or, at least upgrade `LXTerminal` to 256 colors?

Comment: You're confusing terminal emulator (a program such as lxpanel or xterm) with a terminfo name (such as `xterm-256color`). You need to tell the program that the terminal (emulator) running it has the abilities of the `xterm-256color` terminfo entry. Terminal emulators run in X11. You are executing the script in the linux console, which is a terminal but it's not 256 color capable. Start the desktop environment, start lxterminal and try `TERM=xterm-256color python my-cool-curses-script.py`.

Comment: Start the desktop environment: do you mean the GUI? I boot to the command line. And start LXTerminal? If I'm already at the command line I can just go right to `TERM=xterm-256color`...?

Comment: Yes, you must start X (the GUI). If you're running raspian, Try `startx`. Programs like lxterminal must run within the GUI because that makes them do fancy stuff like menus, tabs, nice fonts or 256 colors. The standard linux console only supports 8 colors.

Comment: Ahhh ok I get it now thanks. So a colorful application like `htop` just sticks to those 8 colors to run on the console? If I dumb down my script I should be able to run it straight from the command line at startup, my end goal.

Comment: Right. I think you can also check `curses.COLORS` in python to determine available number of colors and then switch output for 8, 16 and 256 colors. And send me the github link once it's working :-)

Comment: @kba is there a way to see the cursor visibility and color options my Linux text console has? Or, is there an emulator setting I can use on ssh that emulates the raspian linux console?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35942/discussion-between-kba-and-pinhead).